# Using Meta Boxes in a Custom Page Template

Tags: metabox

I'm doing some custom coding and creating a new page template to use for a new page within Wordpress. I'm trying to add a meta box to the page to be displayed as output to the user. I tried to do the following in my page template:

```
add_meta_box( 'submitdiv', __( 'Publish' ), 'post_submit_meta_box', null, 'side', 'core' );
```

When I go to the URL to display the new page I created I get the following error message:
`Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_current_screen() in D:\My Documents\xampp_new\xampp\htdocs\bmt\wp-admin\includes\template.php on line 921`

How can I add meta boxes to be displayed to an end user?

Comment: I want to say that Metaboxes were designed for admin-panel / backend use only but maybe somebody here has a solution for you.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee No, you're right, meta boxes were designed for the admin area of the site.  You'd display the post meta info that you _save_ using a meta box, on the front end.

Answer (score 0):

By default WordPress doesn't load admin classes/function definitions in the front end of the site. You need to explicitly require the files.

As far as I remember requiring `wp-admin/includes/admin.php` would get you most of typical stuff.

Comment: I got rid of the original error by including this file. I did however get another one. I'm still using this code: `add_meta_box( 'submitdiv', __( 'Publish' ), 'post_submit_meta_box', null, 'side', 'core' ); ` The error message I'm getting now is: `Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in D:\My Documents\xampp_new\xampp\htdocs\bmt\wp-admin\includes\plugin.php on line 1676

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in D:\My Documents\xampp_new\xampp\htdocs\bmt\wp-admin\includes\plugin.php on line 1676`

Comment: Actually only including that file on my page creates that warning.

Comment: It's hard to tell because there is no loop at that line in current WP version (4.1).

Comment: Ok, I guess I'll just have to code this portion by myself. Thanks.